# How to create a two by two matrix box

Tags: matrices, boxes

I want to create a two- by-two matrix box like the one in the picture. Do you have any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: This is simple table, isn't it? `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline  & crisis ... & No crisis ...\\ \hline Signal & A & B\\ \hline No Signal & C & D \\ \hline\end{tabular}`

Comment: For simple tables you could use different online editors as, https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables, https://www.latex-tables.com/.

Answer (score 2):

As starting point (with a little bit advanced code) ...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
{
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{| *3{p{5em}|} }
    \cline{2-3}
\mcc{}      & \mcc[2]{\makecell{Events occurs in\\ 
                                the following 24 months}}   \\
    \cline{2-3}
\mcc{}      & \mcc{Crisis}  & \mcc{No crisis}               \\
    \hline
Signal      &   A           &   B                           \\
    \hline
No Signal   &   C           &   D                           \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Introductory text about writing tables you can find on WEB, for example [wiki: Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

[image]

Comment: Have you used the tools online? Ahahah. My best wishes and regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano, no :-). I relay on my own equipment and tools, and of course, when i stuck on help of this site ;-).  Season's Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion with `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
{
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*3{p{5em}}}[corners,hvlines]
            & \Block{1-2}{Events occurs in\\ the following 24 months}   \\
            & \Block{}{Crisis}  & \Block{}{No crisis} \\
Signal      &   A           &   B                     \\
No Signal   &   C           &   D                     \\
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]